# Visualize multiple times series in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, autocorrelation, descriptive-statistics

I'm writing a seminar paper about the topic of forecasting NO2 (h=2) data. My dataset includes 130 timeseries (balanced panel) from 2010 to 2012. At the moment I'm struggling to find a suitable way to visualize that large data set in R. My goal at this stage of my paper is to do explorative/descriptive monitoring of those series (ACF/PACF, time series plots and component plost). For example I try to examine if characteritics of the time series change over time.

Already, I read the "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" book by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos and Roger D. Peng's paper "A Method for Visualizing Multivariate Time Series Data". Unfortunately I still need your advice on the topic.

Comment: You might do better to narrow this down by editing. At the moment it is very broad.

Comment: You don't visualize 130 time series, raw data, all at once for a presentation of ideas. Instead, you break it down and focus on the relevant abstracted information. You provide raw data in a database for people that wish to explore it more in-depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rob Hyndman's presentation on "Visualization of big time series data" might give you some ideas for how to proceed: https://robjhyndman.com/seminars/big-time-series/. In his proposed approach, Rob Hyndman constructs a vector of features for each time series, where the features measure characteristics of that series: lag correlation, strength of seasonality, spectral entropy, etc. Then he uses a principal component decomposition on the features, and plots the first few principal components so that he can explore a lower dimensional space and discover interesting structure and unusual observations. See also: https://github.com/robjhyndman/anomalous.

Roger Peng's article on A Method for Visualizing Multivariate Time Series Data might be useful too: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v025c01/v25c01.pdf.

See also: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07942.pdf.